Add a component to document after app mounted
there is a simple vue application.
I want to make some notifications in my app.
there is a notification component in my project and they will appear after each click on a button for 5 seconds
I want to have a lot of notifs by clicking rapidly on the button.
How can i handle it?
do you have any better solution?
I use this method, it adds <Notification></Notification> to the inspect but it does not render the component (i defined component in App.vue)
sendNotif(){
  const notificationBox = document.getElementById('notification-box')
  let notif = document.createElement('Notification')
  notificationBox.appendChild(notif)
}

(sorry for grammar mistakes)

This is potential XY problem. Generally you can use dynamic  in v-for to render a component any time. If the container is outside  app root element, you can use a teleport.
